# Sinatra Asset Pack isn't Cache Busting @imported files

Tags: sass, sinatra, sinatra-assetpack

I have a Sinatra app with an *application.scss* file which `@import`s all of the rest of the app's SCSS files. It uses the Sinatra asset pack. In the **layout.erb** file I have:

```
 <%= css :application %>
```

Sinatra changes the URL of the compiled CSS file *every time the application.scss file changes*. Unfortunately, it doesn't exhibit this [cache-busting](http://ricostacruz.com/sinatra-assetpack/) behavior when any of the `@import`ed files change. Is there a way to fix this in Sinatra?

Comment: Same issue seems to exist for Stylus CSS preprocessor Stylus.

Comment: I actually fixed this by monkey-patching sinatra. However, if I was going to use sinatra again I probably wouldn't use the Asset Pack at all and handle compilation with gulp.